# Print character given times on the same line

Tags: bash, shell

is there possibility to write character multiple times? For example if i would like to print b on the same line x-times and the value of how many times this character is supposed to be printed would be in variable.
So is there something like...
numberoftimes=5

character * numberoftimes would look like that

bbbbb

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach would be to use a loop.

```
numberoftimes=5
char=b
for ((i=0; i < numberoftimes; i++)); do printf '%s' "$char"; done
```